# In this calculator program, only zero gets displayed as output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void calculation(int x, int y, int z);
main() {
  calculation(15, 5, 1);
}

void calculation(int x, int y, int z) {

  if (z == 1) {
    printf("%d", add(x, y));
  }
  if (z == 2) {
    printf("%d", mul(x, y));
  }
  if (z == 3) {
    printf("%d", div(x, y));
  }
  if (z == 4) {
    printf("%d", sub(x, y));
  }
}

int mul(int x, int y) {
  x * y;
}

int add(int x, int y) {
  x + y;
}

int div(int x, int y) {
  x / y;
}

int sub(int x, int y) {
  x - y;
}

int gugudan(int x) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    printf("%d*%d=%d\n", x, i, x * i);
  } 
}
```

This is the code I want to run by multiplying x with y from the source code that makes the calculator.
I'm trying to print the output, but even with different inputs, the result keeps displaying as zero. 
What's wrong with x,y,z? Or was it wrong somewhere else?

Comment: You are missing the returns in each function.

Comment: Where do you save the result?

Comment: This code doesn’t compile.

Comment: In C function start with return type, you declared functions with int and you need to return something. Syntax of function in C <return_type><function_name>(<arg>){..}

Answer (score 1):

Check the functions you are declaring, for example, the `mul` one.
You declared it to return an `int`, but inside your function, you are not returning anything.

To fix your problem, you need to return the value of the function, which is expected to be an `int`.

So, here is a snipped of what you should do to return the value from a function (i.e., the `mul` function):

```c
int mul(int x, int y) {

   return x * y;
 }
```

So, you should fix this missing `return` on the other functions you developed as well and your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The functions `add`, `mul`, `div`, `sub` need to return an integer(`int`) type value.

In the `mul` function, replace:

```
int mul(int x, int y) {

   x * y;
 }
```

with

```
int mul(int x, int y) 
{ 
  return x * y;
}
```

In the `add` function, replace:

```
int add(int x, int y) {

   x + y;
 }
```

with

```
int add(int x, int y) 
{ 
   return x + y;
}
```

In the `div` function, replace:

```
int div(int x, int y) {

   x / y;
 }
```

with

```
int div(int x, int y) 
{
   return x / y;
}
```

In the `sub` function, replace:

```
int sub(int x, int y) {

   x - y;
 }
```

with

```
int sub(int x, int y) 
 { 
   return x - y;
 }
```

Also, add the function prototypes for `add`, `sub`, `mul`, `div` functions before using them inside the `calculation` functions or else define them before the same.

Answer (score 0):

A very much simplified version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calculate(int, int, short int);

int main(void) {
    int result = calculate(15, 5, 1);

    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}

int calculate(int x, int y, short int op) {
    switch (op) {
        case 1:  return (x + y); break;
        case 2:  return (x - y); break;
        case 3:  return (x * y); break;
        case 4:  return (x / y); break;
        default: break;
    }
}
```

> **Example Output**

```
20    // calculate(15, 5, 1)
```

Although you just forgot to use `return` statements, but you should declare the scopes of function(s) first and definitions after the `main()`.